# How do i make the loop stop repeating in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a beginner in Java and I have to write a program that allows the user to enter in words, then the program returns the word backwards until the user writes "stop". Every time the user enters a word, java outputs it backwards plus the previous word which is outputted and I don't want that.
For example, if I put input pots
it outputs, stop
if I print cat
it outputs potstac
How can I just get java to just output the words backwards without adding it on to the prior words
For example, i want to input in pots
it should output, stop
i want to print cat
it should output, tac

```
import java.util.*;
public class javapdf2413 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        String wordEntered = "";
        String backWords = "";

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter in a word");
            wordEntered = in.next();
            for (int i = wordEntered.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                backWords = backWords + wordEntered.charAt(i);
            }
            System.out.println(backWords);

        }while(!wordEntered.equals("stop"));
    }
```

}

Comment: After System.out.println(backWords); 
again assign empty string to backWords

Comment: It appears `backWords` is never being cleared after it reverses the word that was input. You need to clear that variable, either at the beginning or end of the `do/while` body.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set `backWords` back to an empty string at the beginning of the `do` loop.  If you don't it will just concatenate onto the end of the previous string - which is what you said is happening.  Setting it back to `""` at the beginning of the loop body will essentially "reset" it for the next word.

Like this:

```
do {
    backWords = "";
    System.out.println("Enter in a word");
    wordEntered = in.next();
    for (int i = wordEntered.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        backWords = backWords + wordEntered.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(backWords);

}while(!wordEntered.equals("stop"));
```

Comment: Thank yous so much

Comment: @codinganonymous If this answer helped you solve your issue you should help the individual who posted it by accepting their answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with while loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRun {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String wordEntered = "";
        String backWords = "";

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter in a word");
            wordEntered = in.next();

            if (wordEntered.equals("stop")) {
                break;
            } else {
                for (int i = wordEntered.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    backWords = backWords + wordEntered.charAt(i);
                }
                System.out.println(backWords);
                backWords = "" ;
            }

        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize your variables inside your do loop

```
String wordEntered;
String backWords;

            do {
              wordEntered = "";
              backWords = "";
                System.out.println("Enter in a word");
                wordEntered = in.next();
                for (int i = wordEntered.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    backWords = backWords + wordEntered.charAt(i);
                }
                System.out.println(backWords);

            }while(!wordEntered.equals("stop"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just beware - Strings are immutable objects. Use it with right use case and approach. Try to use StringBuilder for non concurrent code as much as possible where ever you can.